# Sensing soil moisture levels with the RPI - ADC/GPIO & ADC/USB solutions anyone?

Tags: gpio, sensor, piface

I bought a 'Soil Moisture Sensor' like this https://www.tiagoespinha.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2014-05-09-12.51.20.jpg from ebay, and it turns out it's really nothing of the sort (just a resistance meter, with an analog output and a manually configurable comparitor circuit to give a higher/lower type digital output).

Does anyone know of anything on ebay that packages up a better solution.  I have 4 large beds and a 4 shelf plastic greenhouse, and would like to monitor and hence control the watering with a series of networked Pi's, so want a relatively cheap solution that I can connect multiple instances of to one of 5 Pi's, that can give me a reading on which bits of the beds are drying out etc.

I suspect the device I have, is a good start, but would need some kind of ADC converter, ideally that I could connect to a USB bus, or to one of a number of GPIOs, but I don't really want to buy lots of PiFace boards, when all I need is a cheap ADC/resistance solution.

**Answer**
So following research from @Mark Wagoner's suggestion to use a SHT-10 based sensor, I found a couple of things.

1. Firstly that I probably want a gypsom block tensiometer, to sense soil moisture (basically 2 probes in a porus ceramic, such as 2xA2 or Galvanised nails in a block of Plaster of Paris), and
2. Secondly I need a cheap ADC circuit to read those resistances into the pi.

So in solution, I found the following:-

- A link to suggest how to build the tensiometer: http://www.cheapvegetablegardener.com/how-to-make-cheap-soil-moisture-sensor-2/
- And found this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=96135 which suggests a mcp3008 as an inexpensive (<2GBP per IC) low power (2uA) ADC which can connect straight to the Pi's SPI interface, using the PCB design here:-
  https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/368938-raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converter-breakout-for-mcp3008#pcb

**Extra**
I found this http://www.trickle-l.com/new/sensors/ which is a handy list of options for sensing soil moisture

Comment: Having done a bit of research, it seems the best approach from a sensing point of view is a tensiometer, which is to say measuring the resistance accross a porus ceramic.  This chap has got instructions to make something out of galvanised nails, plaster of paris and a bit of hose, and it sounds plausible http://www.cheapvegetablegardener.com/how-to-make-cheap-soil-moisture-sensor-2/  But I still need a means to get the resistance to the pi via some kind of ADC.

Answer (score 1):

Not from eBay but have you looked at this?

[Soil Temperature/Moisture Sensor - SHT10](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1298)

They also have a tutorital on how to hook everything up.

Comment: It looks good, but as I'll probably want 12 or 16 of them, I was hoping for something around the 10GBP/15USD rather than 45/50USD.  A good thought though.

Comment: Looks like the SHT-10 has some potential, with it's serial data line, and it's <5GBP per chip, if I just connect it directly.  Need to figure out if thats feasible though.  http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SENSIRION-SHT10-HUMIDITY-TEMPERATURE-SENSOR-MADE-IN-SWISS-100-ORIGINAL-2ZD4-/111824265043?hash=item1a093edf53:g:~kMAAOSwlV9WR71k

Comment: Definite potential with the SHT10.  Many thanks https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=78939

Comment: Hmm, seems the SHT10 is only an air Humidity testor, and isn't reliable for soil measuring.  I'm intending to encase whatever circuitry I make in silicon and bury it, with wires connecting to my Pi in a water tight box, so this needs to work under soil.